# Is "printf("%d\n",(int)a);" undefined behaviour for unsigned int?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, format-specifiers

If I use wrong format specifier like this :

```
unsigned int i = -1;
printf("%d\n", i);
```

It is invoked **undefined behaviour** because `%u` format specifier for `unsigned`.

**C11 standard § 7.21.6.1(P9):**

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.282) **If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

But, If I write like this:

```
unsigned int i = -1;
printf("%d\n", (int)i); // unsigned to signed
```

Is it also undefined behaviour?

Comment: You probably miss some *language-lawyer* tag

Comment: A signed integer can always be interpreted as an unsigned one, unless you have some exotic crap system with one's complement and trap representations.

Comment: Reopened - the linked question was about signed to unsigned, whereas this is about unsigned to signed which is different. (and this has a good answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it also undefined behavior?

No. The argument is of the correct type. It expects a signed integer, and you provide one. The only caveat is that the outcome is implementation defined (not undefined).

[**6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers - p3**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3)

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

So either it will print *something* (because the conversion happened), or will raise some signal. Whatever happens, your implementation is required to let you know by documenting it.